# Trigger Machine Policy Retrieval & Evaluation Cycle on client via Invoke-wmimethod

Tags: powershell, sccm

Below Invoke-WmiMethod command works well when executing alone on "windows powershell ISE Admin"but when i add this into my script it throws error.

> Invoke-WmiMethod :  At C:\Users\navepand\Desktop\ACME_updates.ps1:42
>   char:1
>   + Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace root\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerS ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMethod

```
{Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace root\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000021}"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
```

Comment: So, this needs administrator permissions. What is the question?

Comment: I can run this without any error in admin powershell ISE but not when i copy the same into my script.

Comment: Like I said.. It needs administrative privileges, so run your script as Admin too.

Comment: added the executable to the shortcut target to run as admin but still the same error.

Comment: It is definitely an access rights problem although it should not be because the user can trigger this via ui. A little bit more is explained here: https://configurationmanager.uservoice.com/forums/300492-ideas/suggestions/12896088-client-actions-command-line-rights unfortunately the details as to how to implement this without admin rights are not really fleshed out

Comment: I have the admin rights and able to run this single command on elevated power shell but not in the script.

Comment: So if you run the script from the same elevated shell it does not work? Or is it just when you run the script via rightclick, run that it does not work?

Comment: run the script from same elevated shell as well as via right click.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Only thing I can advise is to try to paste the whole script into the console and see what happens. PS by design should always present the exact same result when script is run and when content is pasted... So maybe you wrapped your trigger code in some invoke block or something? Really nothing else I can say without seeing it myself. Hopefully someone else is more knowledgeable than me